# Does $A\cos x+B\sin x=\sqrt{A^2+B^2}\cos[x-\arctan(B/A)]$ hold for complex A and B?

Tags: complex-analysis, trigonometry

I have used the trigonometric identity $A\cos x+B\sin x=\sqrt{A^2+B^2}\cos[x-\arctan(B/A)]$ several times in the past. Does this identity hold for complex A and B? Or perhaps it should be $\sqrt{|A|^2+|B|^2}$? If anybody knows the answer, or can send me a reference, I would really appreciate it.

Edit: it appears that this identity holds, with a proof via Mathematica.

Comment: Try a simple case such as $B=0$ or $x=0$. In either case, the left side is $A$.